# ChineseWords python format UnicodeEncodeError , but in django OK

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

demo code like this：

```
#_*_ coding: utf-8 _*_
a = u'北京'
b = u'地图'
c = '{0} {1}'.format(a, b)
```

when i write this in python file(test.py), and then run 'python test.py'. it will raise Exception like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

but, when i run a Django， django methon run demo code， it will be ok。

[django run demo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fokq.png)

```
    python version and python path is totally same.
    python version: 2.7.9
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7, the format *string* also needs to be unicode:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
>>> '{}'.format(u'æ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe6' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'{}'.format(u'æ')
u'\xe6'
```

Your Django example may work because it imports `unicode_literals` somewhere, which will tell the interpreter to see `'foo'` as `u'foo'` instead of the default `b'foo'`:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 23 2017, 15:49:48) 
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> '{}'.format(u'æ')
u'\xe6'
>>> u'{}'.format(u'æ')
u'\xe6'
```

Answer (score 1):

`defaultencoding` has changed:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```